# Add website template for visual studio project

Tags: c#, css, model-view-controller, twitter-bootstrap-3

I already created empty website application. But I want to add some style to it by using online free website templates. I downloaded them. But don't know how to add the css, font, images folders inside the existing project since it already contains some folders for styles and images.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Comment: You have received detailed advice from Willy David Jr. However I am wondering if you are stuck on the simpler problem of how to introduce externally sourced files into your VS project structure. Perhaps you could clarify in your question.

Comment: @camelCase, thanks for the response. What I want is I have new website that I like to add some styling as well as good look. Without doing any styling coding I thought maybe I can use bootstrap templates and design my page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is an empty web application, you can follow these steps:

1. Add your new bootstrap theme or bootstrap css at `Content folder`. Make sure you don't delete your Site.css, just add it, don't overwrite to make sure you have backup. Bootstrap-MyNewTheme.css name will do or whatever you prefer.
2. On your BundleConfig.cs file under `App_Start folder`, replace your css with your new theme:

   ```
           bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css")
           .Include("~/Content/Bootstrap-MyNewTheme.css" //I removed the site.css
           ));
   ```
3. Add your boostrap javascript on your `BundleConfig` as well:

   ```
   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
          "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
          "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"
          ));
   ```

Then you can check your site and adjust any needed changes if there are issues on css. But as I said, if this is a new empty web application, you will just see a new bootstrap look and feel after doing those changes.

Don't forget to apply these changes on your `_Layout.cshtml`

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Comment: Hi Willy, Thanks for the response. I used this website to download bootstrap template.https://startbootstrap.com/template-categories/all/. And I added the css file as well as javascript file. But it didnt work

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work? @KateFernando